# Sharepoint Casecade lookup is not working with Office 365 sharepoint

Tags: jquery, csom, cascading

Trying to figure out cascade lookup with 2 different lists as detailed below.

1. List Name-1:  Facilities, Field name:  Title (Facility)
2. List Name-2:  Deparatments, Field Names:  Facility (Lookup from
   Facilities), Title (Department)

Trying to add jquery and javascript and is not working.  Find below are the codes added to seattle master page and formnew pages.

Please advise how I can get this resolved.

```
https://rubiconoffshore.sharepoint.com/sites/DEV/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js
https://rubiconoffshore.sharepoint.com/sites/DEV/SiteAssets/jquery-3.2.1.js

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $().SPServices.SPcascadeDropDowns({
            relationshipList: "Departments",
                relationshipListParentColumn: "Facility",
                relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
                parentColumn: "Facility",
                childColumn: "Title",
                debug: true
    })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery reference file has to be above the SPServices file.